# Random method in setter method in C#

Tags: c#, random

I am new to C#. I am trying to figure how to use the random method inside a setter. This is how my code looks right now:

```
public class star_wars_figures
{
    private string charactor;
    private int bounty;

    public star_wars_figures(string charactor)
    {
        Charactor = charactor;            }

    public string Charactor
    {
        get
        {
            return charactor.ToUpper();
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == "Han Solo" || value == "Leia")
            {
                charactor = value;
            }
            else charactor = "INCORRECT CHARACTOR!!!!";
        }
    }

    public int Bounty
    {
        get
        {
            return bounty;
        }
        set
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            bounty = rnd.Next(1, 10);
            bounty = value;
        }
    }
}
```

In my main I instantiate with the following:

```
star_wars_figures sw1 = new star_wars_figures("Han Solo");
Console.WriteLine($"Character is: {sw1.Charactor}");
Console.WriteLine($"Money: {sw1.Bounty}");
```

I am trying to generate a random int number in the setter method of the bounty attribute. It's just returning 0.

What have I missed out here?

Comment: 1) Rather than indicating invalid values for `Charactor` by setting the field to an error message, a more conventional approach would be to throw an exception. 2) Declare `private static Random _random = new Random();`, then use that instead of creating new ones all the time. (also what FF said)

Comment: I think the problem with your "0" result, is because of this line `bounty = value;` which sets it after you already setted your random value `bounty = rnd.Next(1, 10);`.

Comment: Your example code never assigns anything to `Bounty`, so the setter is never called and the backing value stays at the initial value of **`0`** (and see the previous comment as well).

Comment: Even if you set `this.bounty` correctly, it's very strange to have to set `x.Bounty = 9;` in order to make `Bounty` return a random value. You probably want `public int Bounty { get { return _random.Next(1, 10); } }`.

Comment: What is the reason you are randomizing `Bounty` in the setter instead of the constructor? Discarding the assigned value and using a random one could be very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't set the bounty in object constructor.
You use only getter for bounty property.
Try to use:

```
public star_wars_figures(string charactor)
{
    Charactor = charactor;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    bounty = rnd.Next(1, 10);
}
```

Comment: I did suspect that logic shouldn't be in a setter :) Thanks

Comment: This is still incorrect. Please remove the `Random rnd = new Random();` statement from the constructor. It needs to be in static field, and definitely not called every time a new random number  is requested.

Comment: Note: If you call `star_wars_figures()` more than once every 20ms or so, you will get duplicate "random" numbers - this is why ja72 is telling you to make it a field. But of course then it would not be threadsafe (if that matters).

Answer (score 4):

"value" (your last assignment) is the value received while calling the setter.

Currently "bounty" is set twice : firstly but your random generator result, and immediately after with "value". Therefore the first value set is lost and not usable anywhere.

You could just remove "bounty = value;" to have it working. 
Nevertheless, a property setter is not the right place to do what you seem to want, I think you have fundamental misunderstanding of how to work with properties and backing fields.

Answer (score 1):

The random number generator needs to be initialized once only, as it used the CPU ticks at the time of initialization for the random number seed. Best practice is to include it into a private static field.

Change your code to

```
public class StarWarsFigures
{
    // Define one instance of the random number generator
    static readonly Random rng = new Random();

    ...
}
```

Now as far as using it inside a setter, it is bad design, as the purpose of the setter is to *set* a property to a specified value. If you want to set the property to a random number initially, then do it at the constructor.

```
    public StarWarsFigures(string character)
    {
        this.Character = character;
        this.Bounty = rng.Next(1, 10);
    }

    public int Bounty
    {
        get { return bounty; }
        set { bounty = value; }
    }
```

Finally, there are some issues with the character string. I assume you want to store it as upper case only, since the getter converts it as such. It is better to do the conversion once at the setter instead. Additionally, when comparing strings, always use `.Equals()` instead of `==` as they mean different things for strings. Finally, you need to convert the set value to upper case also before comparing, or use the `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` option.

```
    public string Character
    {
        get { return character; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals("Han Solo", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
                || value.Equals("Leia", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                character = value.ToUpper();
            }
            else
            {
                character = "INCORRECT CHARACTER!!!!";
            }
        }
    }
```

PS. You might want to fix the typos. `Character` is the correct spelling, not `Charactor`.